# How to delete element from JSON array in Springboot?

Tags: java, arrays, json, spring-boot, jpa

I want to delete the element in JSON array. Data that I use is data of the upload file.

I have this data findById,

```
  {
   "id": "81e5e4b4-c0a0-4836-b1ed-a91e71ffc564",
   "projectNo": "JBB\/0041",
   "projectName": "Project Ridzi",
   "docUrl": "[
               {
                \"uid\":2,
                \"name\":\"Lion Air_23 Nov                 
                 2018_EXMKEF_RIDZIFIRZANDHIHAFIZ.pdf\",
                \"status\":\"removed\",
                \"url\":\"http:\/\/192.168.100.187:3060\/file\/
                 doc_lion_air_23_nov_2018_exmkef_ridzi_firzandhi_hafiz_
                 20190806105118.pdf\",
                \"message\":\"Upload error\"},
                \"name\":\"Undangan Pelatihan Aplikasi PMO PTIP.pdf\",
                \"status\":\"removed\", 
                \"url\":\"http:\/\/192.168.100.187:3060\/file\
                 /doc_undangan_pelatihan_aplikasi_
                 pmo_pt_ip_20190923031243.pdf\",
                \"message\":\"Upload error\"
               },
               {
                \"uid\":\"847d2r0faal\",
                \"name\":\"IJAZAH.pdf\",
                \"status\":\"removed\",
                \"url\":\"http:\/\/192.168.100.187:3060\/file\/
                 doc_ijazah_20190923045123.pdf\",
                \"message\":\"Upload error\"
               },
               {
                \"uid\":\"s6jrt8pvl76d\",
                \"name\":\"logo-434-stmik-jakarta-stik.jpg\",
                \"status\":\"removed\",\"status\":\"removed\",
                \"url\":\"localhost:3060\/file\/img_logo_434
                 _stmik_jakarta_stik_20190925010010.jpg\",
                \"message\":\"Upload error\"
               },
               {
                \"uid\":\"8657rr9q22\",
                \"name\":\"Project- Issue.pdf\",
                \"status\":\"done\",
                \"url\":\"http:\/\/192.168.100.187:3060\/file\
                 /doc_project_issue_20190930023501.pdf\"
               }
              ]"
  }
```

I want to delete elements in docUrl using SpringBoot and JPA.
How to make the code in Repository, Service, and RestController?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you've tried so far.

Comment: There is no JSON array here.  What you have is a JSON object that has **string valued** attribute called `docURL`.  That string happens to be a JSON encoded array.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use json utilities like Jackson or Gson?

I suggest to use Gson, you can read doc [here](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide,)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a specific parameter that is given by an input you simply don't declare it on the model object. Otherwise please specify your question better and I will edit my answer.